# Triggering function on page update (infinite scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a Chrome extension that modifies content on a user's Tumblr dashboard, which uses infinite scrolling. However whenever the use scrolls down, a function needs to run again.

Here's a basic run-down of how I've got it working right now:

- User loads page
- Extensions modifies elements on page
- User scrolls down
- Triggers infinite scrolling
- Next page loads below current one
- More content loads

After that final step, I need step 2 to trigger again and have the new content modified.

I've tried `.bind`ing elements such as the entire `<body>`, the container div around the elements, and to no avail.

How do I trigger a function so that it runs when the content of a page changes (specifically the Tumblr dashboard)?

jQuery is fine, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You should set up a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in your content script to watch for insertions of elements you want to modify.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener) for more details.

Also, the [Mutation Summary library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/) might work well in your case.

Comment: Aren't mutation observers deprecated now?

Comment: @Joshua Events - yes. Observers - no.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `jQuery.ajaxComplete`. It runs whenever there is an ajax request completed. You could have something like

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    if (settings.url === 'tumblr.com/update') { //obviously change the update url
        //do your thing
    }
});
```

Of course the best way would be to find the actual function that gets fired on the scroll and modify it to fire yours on its success. But give that a shot.

Comment: A bit of a problem there that normally extension code runs in a separate context, so jQuery instance (if even present) won't receive those events. It's possible to inject into the page context, but it's an additional layer of complexity.

Comment: @jbarnett "the best way would be to find the actual function that gets fired on the scroll and modify it to fire yours on its success." How would I go about doing that?